# How to install dmake with perl?

Tags: perl, dmake

Can someone please tell me how to download dmake with Perl?

I have tried with CPAN, but this is what I get:

```
cpan> install dmake
Database was generated on Wed, 10 Jul 2019 10:13:05 GMT
Running install for module 'dmake'
'" "' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Checksum for C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\sources\authors\id\S\SH\SHAY\dmake-4.12.2.2.zip ok
Scanning cache C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
Package contains both files[ChangeLog COPYING dmake.exe META.yml NEWS PATCH.TXT README.TXT] and directories[man readme startup]; not recognized as a perl package, giving up
Configuring S/SH/SHAY/dmake-4.12.2.2.zip with Makefile.PL
Running make for S/SH/SHAY/dmake-4.12.2.2.zip
gmake: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
  SHAY/dmake-4.12.2.2.zip
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\gmake.exe -- NOT OK
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'dmake'.
Failed during this command:
 SHAY/dmake-4.12.2.2.zip                      : writemakefile NO -- Package contains both files[ChangeLog COPYING dmake.exe META.yml NEWS PATCH.TXT README.TXT] and directories[man readme startup]; not recognized as a perl package, giving up
```

I have also tried with ppm install dmake, but I got this:

```
Installing package 'dmake'...
Error installing package 'dmake': Could not locate a PPD file for package dmake
```

Comment: (Info on make utilities for Perl: https://www.activestate.com/blog/how-install-cpan-modules-activeperl/)  How did you install strawberry Perl? It should have shipped with 'make'. If you're using VS, it would ship with nmake. And if you're using mingw it would ship with dmake. The dmake utility is not a module on CPAN.

Comment: @DavidO What do you mean ho I installed it? I have installed it from here: https://www.perl.org/get.html

Comment: @DavidO I have to install mod_perl, and for that I am going by the instructions on this site: http://www.aptest.com/atm2/documentation/latest/readme/apache-windows.html and if you see on the website, where it says to execute the "setup_spmp.pl" once I start with executing it says that the 'pip' is not recognized and now I have to first download the dmake.exe, then I have to download the pip and finally I will be able to execute the code.. I am trying to do it for more than 5 hours and still nothing :(

Comment: You're using documentation from the vendor aptest.com to guide you through installing mod_perl, and Apache extension that has its own authoritative documentation at https://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/os/win32/install.html#Installing . I would start over with the Apache documentation, and ask your software vendor to support their toolset.

Answer (score 3):

Not answering the question because it's a XY problem, but giving you the info you need.

The most recent mod_perl2 compiled for Strawberry is [against Perl 5.12](http://downloads.aptest.com/sperl/mp/5.12_x86/), which is [long out of support](http://p3rl.org/policy). Using any other version of Perl is not going to work. You should [ask ApTest](http://www.aptest.com/contact.html) to update and recompile for a current Strawberry and release a new `setup_spmp` helper. They are relying on a dead piece of tech (mod_perl2), so they should either support the required dependency properly or move their application onto a modern stack.